# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot

I have code in my application that try to connect to an external host using HTTPS with a specified certificate.

My code looks like this:

```
    //Load Two Keystores
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "SunJSSE");
    InputStream keystoreInput = new FileInputStream(cerPath);
    keystore.load(keystoreInput, passwd.toCharArray());
    System.out.println("Keystore has " + keystore.size() + " keys");

    // load the truststore, leave it null to rely on cacerts distributed with the JVM
    KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "SunJSSE");
    InputStream truststoreInput = new FileInputStream(cerPath);
    truststore.load(truststoreInput, passwd.toCharArray());
    System.out.println("Truststore has " + truststore.size() + " keys");

    //ssl context
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslcontext.init(null, null, null);
    SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(keystore, passwd);
    Scheme https = new Scheme("https", 443, sf);

    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(https);
    ...
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(new PoolingClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry));
    ...
    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute( targetHost, httpMethod);
```

The variable cerPath contains the path to the certificate (xxxx.pfx) used to establish the connection.

In a standalone application, this works perfectly, but in my spring-boot application, the same code throws this exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
```

I've tested this code inside a normal Spring application, and it works too.

The normal SSL properties () don't work either.

Comment: Not sure why you're loading your keystore and truststore, since you're visibly not using them at all in your `sslcontext.init(...)`. (Perhaps only in your Apache HTTP Client `SSLSocketFactory`, which doesn't seem to make use of the `SSLContext` either.)

Comment: Yes, I think so. But the JVM loads the keystore of the wiremock, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end we've discovered the problem.

We have a dependency in our pom.xml pointing at the framework wiremock:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
        <version>1.43</version>
        <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
              <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

This framework contains a /keystore file inside the jar that produce this problem. When we remove this dependency from the pom, all works fine.